# Determine acceptable content types in ExceptionHandler

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In a Spring application, I have an endpoint which normally returns an image (`produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE`).

I also have `@ExceptionHandler` functions to handle various functions.

I'm trying to find a way to determine, from within the `@ExceptionHandler`, if the client will accept `text/plain` or `text/json` so in the event of an error I can return back one of those, or omit it if they are only expecting `image/png`.

How can I determine what acceptable content types I can return for a given request?

Comment: To the downvoter, care to share why? I've asked a very narrow question. I could provide some example code, but it wouldn't add anything to the question, as for my actual question, I don't know where to start. It's probably just a line or two that I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the answer I came up with. It's similar to YoungSpice's, but it is a little more flexible and uses MediaType directly (which means it'll handle wildcard types like `text/*` and the like):

```
private ResponseEntity<String> buildResponse(WebRequest request, HttpStatus status, String message) {
        HttpHeaders httpHeader = new HttpHeaders();
        List<MediaType> acceptHeader =
                MediaType.parseMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(request.getHeaderValues(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT)));

        if (acceptHeader.stream().anyMatch(mediaType -> mediaType.isCompatibleWith(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))) {
            httpHeader.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            return new ResponseEntity<>("{ \"error\": \"" + message + "\" }", httpHeader, status);
        } else if (acceptHeader.stream().anyMatch(mediaType -> mediaType.isCompatibleWith(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN))) {
            httpHeader.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(message, httpHeader, status);
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(status).body(null);
        }
    }
```

Basically, it uses `MediaType.parseMediaTypes()` to parse the `Accept` header, then I stream through them and use the `mediaType.isCompatibleWith()` function to check if my target is acceptable. This will let it handle if the header has something like `application/*` instead of `application/json` directly.

It also seems like if `Accept` isn't explicitly provided in the request, there is an implied `*/*`, which seems to work as intended.

Answer (score 5):

You can access the request to inspect headers and return an appropriate response. It is standard [Content Negotiation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation).

Here's an example:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {RuntimeException.class})
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMyException(RuntimeException ex, WebRequest request) {
        List<String> acceptableMimeTypes = Arrays.asList(request.getHeaderValues(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT));
        if (acceptableMimeTypes.contains(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok()
                    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
                    .body("hello");
        }
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

There are some arguments that `spring-mvc` can automagically inject into `controller` methods, and `WebRequest` (which is `spring`'s representation of an `http` request) is one of those. If the client has sent an `Accept : text/plain` header with the request, the above example returns the string `hello` if there's a `RuntimeException`. If there's no exception, this logic won't get triggered at all, so the endpoint will just return whatever it normally returns. You can read more about `@ControllerAdvice` and `@ExceptionHandler` [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc).

Of course, be sure to think about the exact exception types you want to handle, and semantically appropriate status codes to return so that the clients know how to correctly interpret the response.